# Converting an Voltera equation to an IVP

Tags: initial-value-problems, integral-equations

I have the following Voltera equation
$$ u(x) = e^x + \int_{0}^{x}u(t)dt.  $$
To convert it on an ODE, I differentiate and find

$u'(x) = e^x + u(x)$ where $u(0) = 1$ but I see the solution is
$$ u'(x) = e^x + u(x) -1$$
Im not finding where the 1 is coming from

Comment: I guess $u'(0)=1$ too.

Comment: When I try to reconstruct the  Voltera equation my answer gives a different result. I was wondering where I went wrong?

Comment: When you write, “but I see the solution is…” do you mean that when you look up the answer in a textbook, they quote the answer as $u’(x) = e^x + u(x) - 1$ ? And that the assigned problem is to write a differential equation satisifed by $u(x)$ if $u$ satisfies the integral equation?

Comment: Its some lecture notes I was following, they gave the solution without working it out

Comment: It looks to me as if the $-1$ is simply a mistake.

Comment: @RicardoMM It’s a first order one. u(0) is enough.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the lecture notes simply have an error. I’m using this answer to explain why I think so.

First, if we differentiate both sides of the Volterra equation, then we get $u’(x) = e^x + u(x)$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. So the $-1$ term is just not there.

Second, as a check, suppose we solve the initial value problem as given in the notes, $u’(x) = e^x + u(x) - 1$, $u(0) = 1$. Then we obtain $u(x) = x e^x + 1$. Inserting this into the right-hand side of Volterra equation gives $x e^x + x + 1$, which differs from $u(x)$. In short, the solution of the initial value problem $u’(x) = e^x + u(x) - 1$, $u(0) = 1$ is not a solution to the Volterra equation.

But the solution of the initial value problem $u’(x) = e^x + u(x)$, $u(0) = 1$, which is $u(x) = x e^x + e^x$, does solve the Volterra equation, as you can check.